# How to show an error message in each of different field for PHP Contact form?

Tags: php, contact-form

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJ5eUgOxITE&list=PLillGF-Rfqbap2IB6ZS4BBBcYPagAjpjn&index=15) and completed this contact form. It works fine, but I want to display a different message in each of the field instead of using a one box. I tried to move

```
<?php if($msg != ''): ?>
            <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
         <?php endif; ?>
```

underneath the input field and that worked great as far as displaying in that spot, but it just shows the same message all at once. It does not show different message separately. How would I approach this from here?

```css
body {
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:sans-serif, "Open-sans";
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    letter-spacing:0.1rem;
}

.navbar {
    background:#333;
    width:100%;
}

.container {
    max-width:1100px;
    margin:auto;
}

.navbar-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size:1.5rem;
    padding:1rem;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

form {
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

.form-group {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin:1.5rem;
}

label {
    color:#333;
    margin-bottom:0.7rem;
}

input, textarea {
    max-width:100%;
    border:0.5px solid darkslategray;
    padding:1.3rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
}

button {
    background:rgb(67, 130, 211);
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    padding:1rem;
    margin:1.5rem;
    border:none;  
}

.alert {
    margin:1.5rem;
    padding:1.5rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    color:#fff; 
}

.alert-danger {
    background-color:rgb(219, 54, 48);
}

.alert-success {
    background-color:rgb(28, 160, 39);
}
```

```html
<?php 
    // Message Vars
    $msg = '';
    $msgClass = '';
    
    // Check for submit
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'submit')){
        // Get Form Data 
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); 
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

        // Check Required Fields
        if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($message)){
            // Passed
            // Check Email 
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ){
                // Failed
                $msg = 'Please use a valid email';
                $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
            } else { 
                // Passed
                $toEmail = 'johnDoe@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'Contact Request From '.$name;
                $body = '<h2>Contact Request</h2>
                    <h4>Name</h4><p>' .$name. '</p>
                    <h4>Email</h4><p>' .$email. '</p>
                    <h4>Message</h4><p>' .$message.'</p>
                    ';

                    // Email Headers
                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Type:text/html;charaset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                    
                    // Additional Headers
                    $headers .= "From: " .$name. "<".$email.">". "\r\n";

                    if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                        // Email Sent
                        $msg = "Your email has been sent";
                        $msgClass = 'alert-success';
                    } else {
                        // Failed
                        $msg = "Your email was not sent";
                        $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
                    }
            }
        } else {
            // Failed
            $msg = 'Please fill in all fields';
            $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Contact US</title>
</head>
<body>
     <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
     <div class="container">
         <?php if($msg != ''): ?>
            <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
         <?php endif; ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label> 
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $name : ''; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $email : ''; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" class="form-control"><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? $message : ''; ?></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit</button>
        </form>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: My current form]

This is my current form.

[image: Form I want to replicate]

I want to make it look like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$msg` variable as an array, instead of a string, to hold errors for specific fields.

```
<?php
    $msg = [];
    
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'submit')){
        //...

        // Check Required Fields
        if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($message)){
  
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ){
                $msg['email'] = [
                    'msg' => 'Please use a valid email'
                    'class' => 'alert-danger'
                ];
            } else { 
                //...

                    if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                        // Email Sent
                        $msg['default'] = [
                            'msg' => 'Your email has been sent'
                            'class' => 'alert-success'
                         ];
                    } else {
                        // Failed
                        $msg['default'] = [
                            'msg' => 'Your email was not sent'
                            'class' => 'alert-danger'
                         ];
                    }
            }
        } else {
            // Failed
           $msg['default'] = [
                'msg' => 'Please fill in all fields'
                'class' => 'alert-danger'
             ];
        }
    }
?>
```

And now in the HTML, you can check if the specific error or message exist and you display it at the right place; default messages at the top and email error under the email input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Contact US</title>
</head>
<body>
     <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
     <div class="container">

        <!-- HERE -->
         <?php if(isset($msg['default'])): ?>
            <div class="alert <?php echo $msg['default']['class']; ?>"><?php echo $msg['default']['msg']?></div>
         <?php endif; ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <!-- ... -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $email : ''; ?>">

                <!-- AND HERE -->
                <?php if(isset($msg['email'])): ?>
            <div class="alert <?php echo $msg['email']['class']; ?>"><?php echo $msg['email']['msg']?></div>
         <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- ... -->
        </form>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And you can actually do the same for any other input you want too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your codes. I have tried a few times, but it hasn't not worked yet. Also implementing your codes makes the emails go directly to the spam folder for some reason. I will get back to you again after more attempts.

Comment: Ok. I've removed some parts of the original code, just to highlight the modifications I made. (I replaced them with comments, both in the php code and the html). Make sure you include them back too.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working great. I will dig deep into it and modify more. One question. What made it go to the spams before you edited?

Comment: Great! For the spam, I'm sure it was because of some missing headers. I'm not sure which one though.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your validation warnings in an array type variable as opposed to a string.

For example, this line:

> $msg = 'Please use a valid email';

You could instead do this:

```
$msg['email'] = 'Please use a valid email';
```

Also I think you want to verify if each of the required fields is present with its own individual `if` check, not all of them together, for example:

> if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($message)){

You can implement as:

```
if (empty($email) || filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $msg['email'] = 'Please use a valid email';
}

if (empty($name)) {
    $msg['name'] = 'Please enter a name';
}

if (empty($message)) {
    $msg['message'] = 'Please enter a message';
}
```

Then in your HTML section, below each of the relevant input fields, you can add:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label> 
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $name : ''; ?>">
    
    <?php if(isset($msg['name'])): ?>
       <p> <?php echo $msg['name']; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

However, in general I have to say this a very oldschool way of using PHP, where you would mix your logic code with your display code.

When you get the hang of it, perhaps you would like to study how Laravel, Symfony, or even CodeIgniter work, where you can use what known as MVC to separate your display from your logic.

As well, you can eventually use a templating engine like Blade or similar to echo out your variables.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and suggestion. Yes, I have been tackling to try your method to get it work. It might take a few days...or a week maybe. I will come back when I get really stuck to the point I can't solve it by myself.

Comment: I'll be glad to help with a specific issue if you get stuck.